# Example how to serve using php an upload from android device

Tags: php, android, http, upload, multipart

i am new in android, but checking the web, and some books i make an app that must send an image and two more params. I just want to make a php serve script that checks if the data was uploaded/sent fine.

So this is my code:

```
public void executeMultipartPost() //throws Exception
    {
        try {
            //convert image to stream, strImage is an image converted to string
            InputStream is          = new ByteArrayInputStream( this.strImage.getBytes("UTF-8") );  
            HttpClient httpClient   = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest    = new HttpPost("http://192.168.12.12/androidlistener/test.php");
            byte[] data             = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            InputStreamBody isb     = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "uploadedFile");
            //These params were filled in before this process

            StringBody sPhoneId     = new StringBody(strPhoneId);
            StringBody sMessage     = new StringBody(strMessage);

            MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
            multipartContent.addPart("uploadedFile", isb);
            multipartContent.addPart("phoneid", sPhoneId);
            multipartContent.addPart("msg", sMessage);
            postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);
            HttpResponse response   = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        } catch (Throwable e)
        {
            // Manejar error
        }
    }
```

So i need a help to make the php script. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an Entity to upload that is a checksum (not slower than md5 remember battery life).  You would then compare server-side the image check-sum with the "uploadedFile" entity.    I somewhat forget how HTTP works but it may be advisable to use Base64 to upload the file.

A simple checksum would look like multipartContent.addPart("checksum", [isb.getContentLength](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html#getContentLength%28%29));

This will check the bytes uploaded without actually checking for consistency, in your average environment this is fine as bits aren't likely to shift in transit unless their is a man-in-the middle.

To be fair you could also just almost just check to make sure that msg is included in the post values, if so it's unlikely that the connection dropped as it would be sent last, but best practice is to be through.

Comment: Thanks for the sugerence, but i need help with the php script my friend. Could you give me an example?